# Ubuntu on Galaxy Tab A

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, samsung

Ubuntu Community

I own a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 9.7in (SM-P555M), and I would like to install Ubuntu on it. I have tried to find information about how to do thi, but unfortunately all information I could find is anecdotic and contradictory.

I understand there is a list of supported devices. However, the list doesn't seem to change ever.

Is it possible to install Ubuntu on my tablet?

Thanks in advanced!!!

Comment: The practical answer is no. It's not impossible, but also not as easy as you'd like.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. That's a little dissapointing; I really expected to install Ubuntu on my tablet. Anyway, thank you!!!